# gRPC based sidecar .NET 5

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net, .net-5, asp.net5

I'm just trying to create a gRPC based sidecar for my services to ease the communication and handling the cross cutting concerns and etc.. I started with a simple client and server gRPC services which share the same proto files. After that I've added some service in the middle to receive the client's gRPC request and doing some message transformation, discover available services etc..

In the middle service, which plays the role of client sidecar (in the future the server sidecar will be added as well), I've used [GRPC.ASPNetCore](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet) package with this option:

`option.IgnoreUnknownServices = true;`

So, I can handle the requests in my custom middleware and my challenges are as below:

**Request Deserialization**

I'm using [protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net) and its [reflection](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/tree/main/src/protobuf-net.Reflection) APIs for generating C# code for my protos on runtime and compiling them with Roslyn to be able to have equivalent CLR type of my protos. After that I'm using protobuf-net's serializer to deserialize the data I've read from the request stream of my custom middleware.

- Can I read compressed messages?
- How can I read server streaming, client streaming or bidirectional streaming?
- Is this approach correct or is there any built-in technology for this scenario?

**Forwarding Request to Another Service**

After discovering the target node (in the case that node accept gRPC request) I have to forward the incoming Http request to the mentioned node. Is there any quick way to forward such request in another service?
Another alternative here is that to create gRPC client on runtime and Invoke it with the deserialized value from the http request stream. but I have to figure out how can I do so.

There are much more questions and ambiguous points in my mind. I would appreciate if you answer my questions or suggest any references.

My project is [here](https://github.com/PouyaMoradian/Grpc-Sidecar/tree/develop).

Comment: "or is there any built-in technology for this scenario?" - just want to check: you know that protobuf-net.Grpc is a thing, yes? (Since you're using protobuf-net for the other bits) - it exposes streaming APIs via IAsyncEnumerable-T

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to get more familiar with it. I wanted to know the opinion of experts (like you) about it. I wish there were more documentation on protobuf-net and its capabilities.

Comment: If the key question in here is about producing gRPC calls: I can't think of clean / easy ways to do that. JamesNK might have thoughts, over on the dotnet gRPC GitHub.

Comment: I do appreciate your help, I'll take a look there. I have some challenges and one of them is creating grpc call on the fly or creating some kind of grpc client to get connected with another sidecar on runtime based on proto files.

Comment: ad compression: if by "compressed messages" you mean the built-in grpc compression, this is something that will be completely transparent to your code (you'll receive the decompressed payload / deserialized messages without needing to do anything:

Comment: ad server streaming, client streaming or bidi streaming:  each of the RPC kinds has its own sever-side handler method signature that is determined automatically from the .proto file. If you for some reason don't know the RPC kind in advance (= you want to handle a "generic" request), you can actually treat all the RPCs as if they were bidi streaming (=the most general case), since on the wire all RPCs "look like" bidi streaming RPCs it's just that e.g. unary calls always only have one request and one response.

Comment: ad forwarding: you can certainly have the server-side handler for a method just use a grpc client to re-invoke that RPC on another server (this of course includes serialization/deserialization overhead). Alternatively, you can forward "generic" requests - a method with custom serializer / deserializer that just forwards the message payloads. The most low-level solution is to just forward the raw HTTP/2 requests directly, but that's an approach that basically skips the grpc code altogether.

Comment: @JanTattermusch Thanks for your suggestions. I want to implement some kind of sidcar to perform some cross cutting actions on requests. For example, forwarding them based on service discovery responses or converting the request into a message to be sent via message queue. To be more specific I want to create aome kind of abstraction over messaging as a sidecar which communicate via grpc with the the client service send the request to the target server's sidecar with gRPC or other protocols. It should cover request/response and streaming etc..